# ThreadPool map returns wrong results (some missed, some multiply)

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

```
threads_data = [[1,2],[3,4]]
pool = ThreadPool(2)
result_list = pool.map(sum, threads_data)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Sometimes **result_list** is wrong [3,3] instead [3, 7]
So results are mixed - answer from first thread is returned two times.
How fix it, please?

Comment: maby it is important: this is simplified example, in reality thread makes some http request and code is executed by celery.

Comment: It is an OBSOLETE package, why don't you migrate to `multiprocessing`? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/threadpool

Comment: I will try this one https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html
Thanks for info.

Comment: @Sraw I can't use Pool instead ThreadPool - "daemonic processes are not allowed to have children"